Generate Sharepoint API acces token using http protocol
I need to download a file located on SharePoint and I figured out the api url needed to do this.
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/company/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('path/file.csv')/$value

This url works perfectly when pasting it in my browser when I am logged in as a user.
In the documentation I found I need to add an Authorization header with an acces token to be able to acces the data via a plain GET request. I followed the steps from the documentation Acces token generation and got a successful response. However when I add the header to a http request I always get the following error.
{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}

The header is set to Authorization : Bearer abcxxx...yxz
I searched the error and found It had something to do with my permissions. However after trying 25 different permission I am all out of ideas on what I am doing wrong. I am generating the code needed for the acces token generation using the following link:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20AllSites.FullControl&state=12345

With XXX the client ID. I also allowed this permission in the Azure portal. However still no luck.
I then moved on to generating the acces token without a user using the following documentation Acces without user. However this resulted in the following error when trying to dowload my file.
Unsupported app only token.

When searching for this error I saw people talking about a command you can run in the Azure terminal. However when I try to open that terminal I get the error No valid subscription.
I have been at this for a really long time and would really appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance
